# Visual Studio reference specific (SQL) database item

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a program in Visual studio, it's a fairly simple menu system for a hypothetical restauraunt and essentially provides the users with a series of forms with questions, and eventually gives them options, they can then build up a list of meal items etc. and get given cost and similar.
Information on the products is stored in an SQL database , such as the name, price, calories etc.

I've had a look around however I'm struggling to, if it's even possible find a way of referencing a specific field or row within the database, either by a name or a Key.
Is this possible?

Regards.

Comment: Incase anyone happens to check this - Would a *select* statement work?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you are asking about is a [Primary Key](http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/primarykey.htm)?

Example Table

```
Product
------------
ProductId|Name  |Cost|
1        |Apple |1.50|
2        |Orange|2.00|
```

Example Query To Pull Only the Apple

```
SELECT Name, Cost
FROM Product
WHERE ProductId = 1
```

How to create a table that will automatically generate these unique keys in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE Product (ProductId INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(50), 
                          Cost FLOAT(2))
```

How data would be inserted to utilize the auto key generation. Followed with a way to get the new identity

```
INSERT INTO Product (Name, Cost) VALUES ('Apple', 1.50)
RETURN @@IDENTITY
```

Hopefully that gives you a push in the right direction?

Comment: Essentially, going to have a button, when i click this button i want the program to fill in a text box with data specified from a row which relates to the button.  So if the button said apple, I'd say for example want it to fill the text box with the word 'Fruit'.

Comment: Are you creating these buttons dynamically? 

You could take the list of Product (Make a call of `SELECT ProductId, Name FROM Product`) and put the results into a list you make buttons off of. Then, when one is clicked make another call to the database to get the info about it. Something like `SELECT [Type] FROM ProductType WHERE ProductId = @ProductId` and set `@ProductId` to whatever you're working on (like 1 for Apple).

Comment: Jeremy is correct. However, it does sound like you should read up quite a bit on relational databases (maybe that is the reason for the homework?). This site is not a teaching site, but a specific Q&A site. So, generally, open-ended questions (which this is becoming), are often shut down to keep the site clean and Q&A. I just wanted to point that out, because like I said, that is where this sounds like it is going

Comment: I apologise that this comes across pretty open ended, while it is tagged under homework , this is more self styled coursework I'm doing for a project, I've used Visual Studio to develop a program in the past, that contained a linked SQL Database, however it merely loaded each row in order displayed it and then progressed. My question was more on how precisely to use Select SQL statements within the visual studio environment in order to select precise data based on a user's interaction and assign that data to objects such as text boxes.